# How is it possible that the wave of an electron (a particle with mass) with shorter wavelenghth has a faster phase velocity?

Tags: electrons, mass, velocity, frequency

How is it possible that the wave of an electron (a particle with mass) with a shorter wavelenghth has a faster phase velocity? Does omega (angular frequency) grow faster than k (wave number)? Does it mean that omega is not a linear function of k? 1) If omega and k were always the same then we would have the same phase velocity for every k and omega. 2) If omega is directly proportional to k, it would also mean that their ratio would be the same for every value of omega and k.

Comment: What do you think is the relationship between omega and k for a free particle?

Comment: Let´s say that it´s k squared divided by 2m.

Comment: Then what is your question? Is this a linear relationship?

Comment: No, it´s not. So, the bigger is the wave number (shorter wavelength), the bigger is the ratio between the angular frequency and the wave number (phase velocity).